# Is there any way to use a non-apple remote control with a Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, keynote, remote-control

I own a Mid 2012 15" MacBookPro, non-retina model. It's from the era they still packed an IR receiver but not the remote.

Is there any way I can hook up a third-party remote control to control keynote? I found the Apple TV remote is functional with "Sirimote" but it's way out of my budget.

I already tried RemoteBuddy & iRed with an old remote to no avail.

Comment: What version is your operating system on the Mac?

Comment: There are/were apps to run on an iPhone which did remote very well...

Comment: You can get Apple Remotes on eBay very cheaply. The Aluminium and White Plastic ones both work perfectly with that MBP.

Comment: Do you have an Android phone with IR blaster?  If so the free [TV Apple Remote Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ir.remote.control.appletv) app works fine despite the "TV" in the name (with my 2007 MBP at least).

Comment: I'm running latest Mojave 10.14.6, tried apps using my iPhone, I need to keep wifi+bluetooth on both devices and not always works, it's not really useful for long presentations.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is IR, universal remotes will work, too.

Comment: Wow, this is something I was hoping for! It's way cheaper than buying an Apple one, and I can even use rechargeable batteries, instead of button cell. Thank you!